# Are real subgroups of $O_F(\mathbb{C})$ contained in $O_F(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, bilinear-form

Assume we have a subgroup $G \subset O_F(\mathbb{C})=\{X \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})\mid X^t FX=F\}$ where $F$ is a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ invariant under $G$.

**My question goes as follows:**
If we now additionally have, that $G$ is in fact already a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ then does this imply $G \subset O_F(\mathbb{R})=\{X \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})\mid X^t FX=F\}$?

Comment: Yes. You have $G \subseteq O_F(\mathbb{C})$ and $G \subseteq GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, hence $G \subseteq O_F(\mathbb{C}) \cap GL(n,\mathbb{R}) = O_F(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Is it ok, if i may ask another related question?

Comment: Yes, if you  just forgot some detail, you may edit your question. Or you may ask a new question.